# How to render multiple checkboxs and radio buttons in view from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc. the below is a sample of working with multiple check boxes and radio buttons but now i have to generate or inject in my page multiple multiple check boxes and radio buttons as per database. i have two master table called SEX and Hobbies. now i want to show as many as checkboxes as per the records for hobbies in db and the same way i want to show radio buttons for sex.

```
<form id='your-form' action='@Url.Action("Action","Controller")' method='post'>
     <b>Gender</b><br />
     <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Male' /> Male <br />
     <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Female' /> Female <br />
     <hr />
     <b>Hobbies</b><br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Reading' /> Reading <br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Sports' /> Sports <br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Movies' /> Movies <br />
     <input type='submit' value='Update Profile' />
</form>
```

i do not know how to achieve it in mvc. do i need to iterate in view html or there is some other way to achieve it. i just want to work with check boxes not checkbox list or radio button list.

also like to know how to capture those value back when user click on submit button after selecting check boxes and radio buttons. if it is done by viewmodel then it would be great.

it will be great help if some one discuss with code sample just to better visualization purpose.

thanks

Comment: Create a model/view model, pass your model to the view, use strongly typed html helpers to generate your html and then post back the model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `ViewModel` and then pass it back e.g.

**View Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool CheckBox1 { get; set; }
    public bool CheckBox2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ViewModel()
    {
        CheckBox1 = true,
        CheckBox2 = false,
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(ViewModel model)
{
    // model will have your checkbox results
}
```

**View**

```
@model ViewModel

<form id='your-form' action='@Url.Action("Action","Controller")' method='post'>
     <b>Gender</b><br />
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.CheckBox1, "Male")

     @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.CheckBox2, "Female")

     <input type='submit' value='Update Profile' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a model to your view and use Editor Templates.

In this case create a class which will hold the checkbox value and text for the check box say

```
class HobbyCheckBoxViewItem
{
       public string Text {get;set;}
       public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
       public string HobbyID {get;set;}
}
```

Model for your main View

```
class SampleForm
{
     public bool Gender {get;set; }
     public List<HobbyCheckBoxViewItem> Hobbies {get;set; }
}
```

Now in your view use @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Hobbies). For this your need to create EditorTemplates forlder in your view and create template for Hobbies List. Before that have look into EditorTemplates in MVC.

Populate your Hobbies List from the database.

When the user submits the form, your Hobbies List will be automatically populated based on the user selection. Don't forget to put hobby ID in the hidden field in your hobby editor template.

Comment: sorry for one request. it would be much easier if u post full working code.

Comment: why u suggest Editor Templates ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this easily, you will need a model backing up your view. Assume you have a model with two properties of `List<Sex>` and `List<Hobbies>`
This will be 
`@model Namespace.YourModel`

```
@Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
 <b>Gender</b><br />
 @for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.Sex.Count(); i ++)
  {
     @Html.RadioButton("gender",Model.Sex[i].Name) @Model.Sex[i].Name <br />
   }
 <hr />
 <b>Hobbies</b><br />
 @for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.Hobbies.Count();i++)
  {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>Hobbies[i].IsChecked) @Hobbies[i].Name

  }

<input type='submit' value='Update Profile' /> 
}
```

This assumes that your Hobbies model has a 'Name', and IsChecked Property Property, change the name property to what ever your DB list uses, 
This particular view Will post to any model that has 
Properties of type `List<Hobbies>` and `string Gender`.

Comment: here u use CheckBoxFor() but for radio button u used RadioButton html helper. i just like to know RadioButtonFor() html helper does not exist?

Comment: It does, but will not generate the html you are looking for, the modelBinder looks for the name when binding back the model.
Html.RadioButtonFor will generate duplicate values of the Gender property, You can achieve the same result by using RadioButtonFor and overriding value property I suppose, but that would equate to more code, RadioButton is sufficient in most cases.

Comment: `RadioButtonFor()` is exactly what OP should be using for the `Gender` property! `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male")` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Female")`

Comment: My code was to account for more genders, or a similar situation that might arise in the future.

Comment: All you posting back is multiple controls with `name="gender"` which will have no relationship to the model and cannot be bound. If its multiple genders (which of course makes no sense - how can a person have genders) it would be `m => m[i].Gender, "Male"`

Comment: At the moment only two genders are known, that does not in anyway mean that only two exist. This cannot be a topic that can be discussed here, but assume more genders do pop up, and from the OP's question, he is getting the values from the database, then wouldn't it be correct to use the names from the DB instead of hard coding the values?